# ionic app to ionic material or angular material

Tags: angular-material, ionic-material

Just want to know how can I upgrade my ionic + angularJS app to ionic material + angular or angular matrial + ionic app.

I have a lot of code already written and do not want to change whole app. is there any way to inject material to existing ionic app?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy: https://github.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material

As you can read in here github.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material#can-i-use-ionic-and-angular-material-together, it's much better to use Ionic Material than Angular Material for ionic.

Here you have another module for Ionic with Material, but I have not tested this: https://github.com/delta98/ionic-material-design-lite.

If you want just simply changes (no angular directives), try getmdl.io

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `angular matrial + ionic` but  I have used `http://ionicmaterial.com/`,

They guys at `ionicmaterial`, are doing a fantastic job, However by the time I tried to use it (about 1-2 months back), it some issues and I had to give it up halfway. And if you already have a lot of code it will be bit of a challenge to change them.

I'm currently using `http://materializecss.com/', (its not elegant as`ionicmaterial`, but I have more control over the css, js etc.. and works pretty well.

and there are few themes in [here](http://market.ionic.io/themes) as well

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic + Ionic material** is the best choice.

Angular Material + Ionic are fairly incompatible (you can add them to the same project, but the styling will be extremely inconsistent and none of the UI components will work cross-framework, eg. an ionic side menu with material tabs). Ionic is 1.0 and angular material is still pre-1.0.

It's better to use ionic framework and ionic material together as ionic material is a "material extension" to Ionic.
[Ionic Material](https://github.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material) extends the actual ionic framework namespace (in JS), renders material styles on the ionic elements (following ionic's conventions), and will aim to follow the releases of Ionic, and support material theming, ink, and motion for any new Ionic release, which explains why ionic material + angular would not be a great choice either.

Link poster by machnicki explains it all.